# Error pecl install oci8-2.2.0 - Try to build container on apple with chip silicon (M2)

Tags: php, docker, pecl, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I pass the day on this problem, the docker file work perfectly on windows.
When I launch docker-compose up I have this error :

### `=> ERROR [web 11/54] RUN echo 'instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0            7.0s

> [web 11/54] RUN echo 'instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0:
> #0 0.201
> #0 0.201 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PEAR/REST.php on line 187
> #0 0.201 PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 187
> #0 0.201 PHP Stack trace:
> #0 0.201 PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/php/peclcmd.php:0
> #0 0.201 PHP   2. require_once() /usr/share/php/peclcmd.php:31
> #0 0.201 PHP   3. PEAR_Command_Install->run() /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php:316
> #0 0.201 PHP   4. PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Common.php:270
> #0 0.201 PHP   5. PEAR_Downloader->download() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php:666
> #0 0.201 PHP   6. PEAR_Downloader_Package->initialize() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader.php:296
> #0 0.201 PHP   7. PEAR_Downloader_Package->_fromString() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader/Package.php:189
> #0 0.201 PHP   8. PEAR_Downloader->_getPackageDownloadUrl() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader/Package.php:1706
> #0 0.201 PHP   9. PEAR_REST_10->getDownloadURL() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader.php:870
> #0 0.201 PHP  10. PEAR_REST->retrieveData() /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST/10.php:74
> #0 0.201 PHP  11. PEAR_REST->useLocalCache() /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php:80`

`End of the error :
#0 6.963 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so when searching for -lclntsh

#0 6.963 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh

#0 6.963 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

#0 6.964 make: *** [Makefile:209: oci8.la] Error 1

#0 6.969 ERROR: `make' failed

------

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c echo 'instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
There a part of my Dockerfile
`

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y \
  curl \
  git \
  nano \
  apache2 \
  php \
  php-cli php-curl php-gd php-iconv php-imap php-mbstring php-pgsql php-xsl php-zip php-xdebug php-imagick\
  php-dev php-pear build-essential libaio1 php-mailparse php-bcmath\
  libapache2-mod-php \
  postgresql-client \
  unzip \
  zip \
  xsltproc \
  libxml2-utils\
  libmcrypt-dev\
  unixodbc-dev

# Oracle instantclient
ADD docker/conf/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip /tmp/
ADD docker/conf/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip /tmp/
RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64
RUN unzip -qq /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64
RUN unzip -qq /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64
RUN mv /usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/instantclient_21_4 /usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib
RUN echo /usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN echo 'instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0
RUN echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
RUN echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib\"" >> /etc/environment
RUN echo "ORACLE_HOME=\"/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib\"" >> /etc/environment
RUN echo "ServerTokens Prod" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN echo "ServerSignature Off" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib\"" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
RUN echo "export ORACLE_HOME=\"/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib\"" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
RUN ldconfig
ADD docker/conf/oracle/php-7.4.3.tar.gz /tmp/
RUN cp -r /tmp/php-7.4.3/ext/pdo_oci /tmp
RUN cd /tmp/pdo_oci && \
    phpize && \
    ./configure --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib && \
    make install
```

- I tried to delete all, and reinstall.
- Check the box on desktop docker to use rosetta.
- Launch this cmd : softwareupdate --install-rosetta
- Delete all and retry with Colima

I got all time the same issue.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. `echo 'instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/21.1/client64/lib' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0` looks strange, I can't find any example with this syntax, please share the source of this code.

Comment: This install looks pretty much the same as what I use and I don't see any issues. Note that you don't need either the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the `ORACLE_HOME` env vars for the OCI module to work once it's compiled. I'll also point out that PHP 7.4.3 and InstantClient 21.4 are both pretty pretty old, so I'd recommend at least starting w/ 7.4.33 and 21.10 before spending time debugging.

Comment: @A.L The syntax is correct -- `pecl install oci8` will stop and prompt for this string to be manually entered, so the easiest way to automate it is to pipe it through stdin.

Comment: Thanks all.
Alex, I tried to change instantClient but I have the same error.

Comment: Is the `Dockerfile` complete? There is no base image. Can you modify the recipe so that the `.zip` files are downloaded in the `Dockerfile`? Otherwise no one else can try to build it.

Comment: I'll try to compile on the server.

Comment: What's your 'FROM' line?  What OS are you actually using in the container?

Comment: Ubuntu.
I think socketio and Oracle don't like the apple silicon. So the solution is to build image on the server and pull the image.

Comment: If you found any solution, please post an answer - don't add it to your question

Comment: Please share all the code that allow to build the image (including `FROM` and the `.zip` files), otherwise no one can replicate the issue and it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
I'm not sure how my colleague solved the problem, but the image was built on the server, and I pulled the image with `docker-compose pull`.

So no more problems with the build because it was prebuilt